# Get Clipboard History in Python (win + v)

Tags: python, windows, clipboard, clipboarddata

On Windows 10/11 Win+V brings up the clipboard manager containing a history of the content you last copied. Is there any way to access this content in Python?

I know I can get the last copied item with: ctypes, tkinter, win32clipboard, pyperclip etc. but I'm looking for a way to get the whole history (including the images if possible).